# LINQ to XML with multiple elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am playing around with some LINQ to XML and I have been unable to get my query working the way I want it to. I am able to get a single element working like firstName, but when I add another I see red underlines in VS telling me an object reference is missing. I am assuming this is a syntax issue. I am fairly new to LINQ so sorry for the dumb question. I have been unable to find an example that covers my scenario. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
        Member MyMember = new Member();
        MyMember.fName = "Willy";
        MyMember.lName = "Wonka";
        MyMember.Address1 = "333 Chocolate Avenue";
        MyMember.City = "Candytown";
        MyMember.State = "North Carolina";
        MyMember.Zip = "05684";


        List<Member> mlist = new List<Member>();
        mlist.Add(MyMember);


        XElement customersElement = new XElement("primaryNames",
                                                  from Member in mlist
                                                  select new XElement("firstName", Member.fName),
                                                         new XElement("last", Member.lName),
                                                         new XElement("address", Member.Address1),
                                                         new XElement("city", Member.City),
                                                         new XElement("state", Member.State),
                                                         new XElement("zip", Member.Zip));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to iterate a list, each element in the list is a child element of `primaryNames`. So create another child element `primaryName` as said below.

```
    XElement customersElement = new XElement("primaryNames",
                                          from mem in mlist
                                          select new XElement("primaryName",
                                                    new XElement("firstName", mem.fname),
                                                    new XElement("last", mem.lname),
                                                    new XElement("city", mem.city),
                                                    new XElement("state", mem.state)
                                                    ));
```

Comment: Thank you. I see where my mistake was now and everything is working as expected.